# cakephp auth component when I submit login

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, authentication

when i submit login 
I got
     Error: LoginsController could not be found.

this Appcontroller

```
class AppController extends Controller {
var $helpers = array('Html','Form','Ajax','Javascript','Session');
   var $components = array('Auth','Session');

  function beforeFilter() {
    //parent::beforeFilter();
   $this->Auth->userModel = 'Member';
    $this->Auth->allow('*');
    $this->Auth->authError='Please Login for view this page';
    $this->Auth->loginError = 'Username or Password does not match';
    $this->Auth->loginRedirect = array('Controller'=>'Members','action'=>'dashboard');
    $this->Auth->logoutRedirect = array('Controller'=>'Members','action'=>'index');

    ($this->set('admin',$this->isadmin()));
    ($this->set('logged_in',$this->logged_in()));
    ( $this->set('userUsername',$this->userUsername()));
}

function isadmin(){
    $admin = FALSE;
    if($this->Auth->user('priority') == 'admin')
            {
        $admin = TRUE;
    }
    return $admin;
}
     function logged_in(){
     $logged_in = FALSE;
    if ($this->Auth->user())
              {
          $logged_in = TRUE;
      }  
      return $logged_in;
 }
 function userUsername(){
     $userUsername = NULL;
     if($this->Auth->user())
             {
         $userUsername = $this->Auth->Member('username');
     }
     return $userUsername;
}
```

}

I try to search in stackoverflow but I can't found thank for answer

Comment: Should I switch to authsome or not, because I began to hate the auth component.But there is a problem or difficulty that increases when using ACL or not.

Comment: Show your users-controller. There is no need your a `LoginsController`. Also, controller names should always be singular!

Answer (score -1):

What is happening is that you need to create a LoginsController that extends the AppController and in that controller you will handle the logic for the login. When you go to the url /login, it will automatically look for that controller unless you create a route specifying otherwise.

Comment: I'm don't know I follow in the tutorial in youtube

Comment: That's not how the auth-component works. Theres no need for a login-controller!